# Any good client-side open-source dashboard framework?

Tags: open-source, charts, dashboard, d3.js

I am looking to build a client-side dashboard framework where a user can create a new dashboard, add portlets, position them along a grid system, resize, close, ....

The dashboard look and feel should be controllable with CSS.
I am looking for a commercial-friendly open source solution to be used to create a d3.js based  interactive dashboard system.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Cube](http://square.github.com/cube/) and [jSlate](http://jslate.com) are two options.

Comment: Cube doesn't look like a dashboard tool, and I can't find any way to download the jSlate source code.

Comment: jSlate is on GitHub: https://github.com/rasmusbergpalm/jslate

Comment: Cube is discontinued. jSlate has only a code and graph next to each other.

Answer (score 21):

[Dashing](http://shopify.github.io/dashing), with a demo [here](http://dashingdemo.herokuapp.com/sample). [Licensed](http://shopify.github.io/dashing/#license) under the [MIT License](http://opensource.org/licenses/MIT)

Answer (score 17):

[freeboard](https://github.com/Freeboard/freeboard) and [freeboard.io](http://freeboard.io)

Licensed under MIT.

Full disclosure: I am the developer behind freeboard, but there are many happy users who will also vouch for it.

Answer (score 6):

[AtlasBoard](http://atlasboard.bitbucket.org/) by Atlassian. Node based, clean and fast to develop with. Apache license.

Answer (score 2):

There are also:

- AdminLTE http://almsaeedstudio.com/preview
- devoops http://devoops.me/themes/devoops/

Answer (score 1):

Another free tool is [jChartFX](http://www.jchartfx.com/), which is built by SoftWareFX - a company that has a lot of graphical presentation layer options for various scenarios.

Comment: Is it open source? What about licensing? From what I've read it's commercial with non-transferable licenses.

Comment: Same question. Is it open source? What about licensing?